# c++ wcout std::map value

Tags: dictionary, c++

I have a std::map called 'prompts' which is declared like this:

```
std::map<const int, wstring, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::wstring> >> prompts;
```

and it stores int 'key' and wstring 'value' pairs. If I do this:

```
wcout << prompts[interpreter->get_state()];
```

The compiler (vc10) complains

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What do I have to do to get the wstring value returned from the map to print with wcout? Some sort of cast? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, you are missing an `std::`

`std::map<const int,`**std::**`wstring, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::wstring> >> prompts;`

You should write `std::wcout` instead of `wcout`.

I just tried this code and it compiles.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<const int, std::wstring, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::wstring> >> prompts;
    std::wcout << prompts[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right...I also had included <string.h> instead of <string> which wasn't helping either....stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for the help...

Comment: I'd blame the language, not you.